# Highcharts - How can I show arrow in "solidgauge"?

Tags: highcharts

I want to show arrow like `speedometer` in `Highcharts solidgauge graph`. Is it possible?

[image]

Plugin Link: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-solid
Version: **4.1.9**

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am trying to change options from here http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-solid/

Comment: you may customize http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/wCJjE/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the example from http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-solid/

you just have to add a second Series with the type 'gauge' like this:

```
{
  name: 'Whatever',
  type: 'gauge',
  data: [80]
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/doc_snyder/j5owogor/

Comment: Yesterday fiddle was working but its not working today, even I tried to use your example in my local setup but its not working there also. 
  I found same error in both in fiddle and in my local: 
uncaught exception: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17

Comment: I can see that too. Looks like they released the highcharts v4.1.10 yesterday and it broke that example. I set the version to the last release in the fiddle and now it is working again.

Comment: how to set max Value in the yAxis section, it will take only 5, 10,,25 50, 100,200... if i have give max value 340 it will show only 250 in the chart.

Comment: Its working adding the following line refer : min: 0,
                max: maxCount,
                tickPositioner: function() {
                    return [this.min, this.max];
                }
 https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5505